# Javascript - Prototype function which runs a simulation using the date function

Tags: javascript, prototype, simulation

I am trying to add two functions to my program. One of them will change the available property of the prototype from true to false and set the checkout date. The checkout date needs to be set to the current date minus some random number of days (days should be randomized).

My try:

```
    Book.prototype.checkOut = function() {
    this.Available = false;
    var temp = new Date(1000000000);
    var date = new Date() - temp;
    var res = new Date(date);
    this.checkoutDate = res;
};
```

The second one checks the current date and the checked out date and if it's greater than 14 days it returns true.

My try:

```
    Book.prototype.isOverdue = function() {
    var singleDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
    var difference = todayDate - this.checkoutDate.getTime();
    if (Math.round(difference / singleDay) >= 14) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

All my code:

```js
var Book = function(title, Available, publicationDate, checkoutDate, callNumber, Authors) {
  this.title = title;
  this.Available = Available;
  this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
  this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
  this.callNumber = callNumber;
  this.Authors = Authors;
};

var Author = function(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
};

var Patron = function(firstName, lastName, libCardNum, booksOut, fine) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.libCardNum = libCardNum;
  this.booksOut = booksOut;
  this.fine = fine;
};

Book.prototype.checkOut = function() {
  this.Available = false;
  var temp = new Date(1000000000);
  var date = new Date() - temp;
  var res = new Date(date);
  this.checkoutDate = res;
};

Book.prototype.checkIn = function() {
  this.Available = true;
};

Book.prototype.isOverdue = function() {
  var singleDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
  var difference = todayDate - this.checkoutDate.getTime();
  if (Math.round(difference / singleDay) >= 14) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

Patron.prototype.read = function(book) {
  this.booksOut.add(book);
}

Patron.prototype.return = function(book) {
  this.booksOut.remove(this.booksOut.length);
}

var authors = [];
authors[0] = new Author("Auth", "One");
authors[1] = new Author("AutL", "Two");

var catalog = [];
catalog[0] = new Book('Bk1', true, new Date(2001, 1, 21), new Date(), 123456, authors);
catalog[1] = new Book('Bk2', true, new Date(2002, 2, 22), new Date(), 987656, authors);
catalog[2] = new Book('Bk3', true, new Date(2003, 3, 23), new Date(), 092673, authors);
catalog[3] = new Book('Bk4', true, new Date(2004, 4, 24), new Date(), 658342, authors);
catalog[4] = new Book('Bk5', true, new Date(2005, 5, 25), new Date(), 345678, authors);

var patrons = [];
patrons[0] = new Patron('Pat1', 'Wat', 1, catalog, 0.00);
patrons[1] = new Patron('Pat2', 'Wot', 1, catalog, 0.00);
patrons[2] = new Patron('Pat3', 'Wit', 1, catalog, 0.00);
patrons[3] = new Patron('Pat4', 'Wet', 1, catalog, 0.00);
patrons[4] = new Patron('Pat5', 'Wut', 1, catalog, 0.00);

//while loop or for loop for 90 days
//For loop over catalog
//forloop over patrons 
//Check if available , if so check book out
//If not available check book back in
//check checking back in check to see if book is overdue and if so add a fine
//When down loop over patrons to see their fees

for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < catalog.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < patrons.length; k++) {
      var fine = patrons[k].fine;
      if (catalog[k].Available) {
        catalog[k].checkOut;
      } else {
        catalog[k].checkIn;
        patrons[k].read;
      }
      if (catalog[k].isOverdue) {
        fine = fine + 5.00;
      }
      patrons[k].fine = fine;
    }
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < patrons.length; i++) {
  console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has checked out the following books:");
  for (j = 0; j < patrons[i].booksOut.length; j++) {
    console.log(patrons[i].booksOut[j].title);
  }
  console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has fine amount: $" + patrons[i].fine);
}
```

When I run the program, everything runs but the patrons end up getting huge fines, and as this is supposed to be a randomized simulation, I can't seem to figure out what I should do differently to fix that problem.

Comment: I would add an `expireDate` variable to your `checkOut` function. Then check for that variable and calculate the fine on difference between `expireDate` and current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> The checkout date needs to be set to the current date minus some random number of days (days should be randomized).

yet there is no radomisation in:

```
Book.prototype.checkOut = function() {
  this.Available = false;
  var temp = new Date(1000000000);
  var date = new Date() - temp;
  var res = new Date(date);
  this.checkoutDate = res; 
};
```

The expression `new Date(1000000000)` returns a new date for 1970-01-12T13:46:40.000Z, so

```
new Date() - temp;
```

returns a large number, like 1491816607452, which is about 1726 days. It sets the same expiry date for all patrons for all books, so they all end up with the same fine.

If you want to have patrons checkout books for random periods of say 10 to 20 days, then:

```js
// Return a random  integer between start and end inclusive
// Does not check if start or end are integers
function randInRange(start, end) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1)) + start;
}

// checkOut method as function for demo
var checkOut = function() {
  // Set randDays to random days from 10 to 20
  var randDays = randInRange(10,20);
  // return date minus randDays  
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - randDays);
  return date;
};

// Some tests, 10 dates randomly 10 to 20 days ago
for (var i=10; i; i--) {
  console.log(checkOut().toString());
}
```

The *checkOut* method is a plain function that you can modify to suit your *Book* constructor. But rather than radomising your test data, it should be set to specific values so you know exactly what the results should be. Also, you should test known problematic cases to ensure they are handled correctly.

I haven't looked at the rest of your code in any detail.